# how to enable http securely by using ini_set

Tags: php

I have used the ini_set function but when I checke my chrome inspection, my http is still not checked.

I have tried to use several ini_set functions such as the following but also thought that it should have prevented my javascript code from executing

```
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', '1');
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', '1');
session_start();




<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = document.cookie;
    alert(a);

</script>
```

Comment: I am just wondering because if I used strip_tags, wouldn't that prevent the user from inserting the javascript code?

Comment: but if you were to logout of a site, wouldn't this destroy your session anyway?

Comment: would the following be correct for a live server?

Comment: session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', 'www.pianocourse101.com', false, true);

Comment: I inserted that into my login page but my http is still not checked